# What is (explicitly) known about the SL(n,C) character varieties of 3-manifolds?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, character-varieties

The $SL(2,{\bf C})$ character variety of a 3-manifold with 1-cusp $M$ (like a knot complement in the 3-sphere)  essentially coincide with the variety defined by the A-polynomial. Those polynomials are known explicitly for torus knots, and tabulated for many hyperbolic knots, e.g. on Culler's webpage.

I am wondering if the $SL(n,{\bf C})$ character varieties (denote it $X_n(M)$) are also known (by a set of polynomial equations for instances) in some examples, like the complement of torus knots, or of the figure-8 knot ?

Another question: it is known that $X_n$ at a smooth point has complex dimension $(n - 1)$. Does there exist "remarkable" subvarieties of complex dimension $1$ in $X_n(M)$ ?

Comment: There's this paper: 
http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1111.4338

Comment: and these:

http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3511
http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.4329
http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.2589


and many, many more, as well as many articles on SU(n) 
representations for n>2.  Follow the references on these.

Answer (score 4):

The answers at this [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/234634/12218) might be of interest.

As implied by the comments, there is a large body of work on this topic.

Here are some authors (definitely not exhaustive) who have worked out the exact structure of character varieties of 3-manifold groups:

1. [Michael Heusener](https://arxiv.org/search/?searchtype=author&query=Heusener%2C+M)
2. [Emily Landes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3323)
3. [Melissa Macasieb](https://arxiv.org/search/math?searchtype=author&query=Macasieb%2C+M+L)
4. [Vicente Muñoz](http://www.mat.ucm.es/%7Evmunozve/articles.html)
5. [Kate Petersen](http://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Epetersen/publications.html)
6. [Joan Porti](https://arxiv.org/search/?searchtype=author&query=Porti%2C+J)

In particular, the answer to your first question is **yes**.  See:

1. [*Geometry of the SL(3,C)-character variety of torus knots*, by
   Vicente Muñoz, Joan Porti](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4784) for torus knots and $n=3$, and
2. [*The SL(3,C)-character variety of the figure eight knot*, by
   Michael Heusener, Vicente Munoz, Joan Porti](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04451) for the figure eight knot and $n=3$.

For your second question, I recommend reading generalities about tangent spaces to character varieties in:

[*Character Varieties*, by Adam Sikora](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.2589v3.pdf).

With respect to local deformations for (finite volume hyperbolic) 3-manifold groups, the following references answers your second question positively:

1. [*Local coordinates for SL(n,C) character varieties of finite volume hyperbolic 3-manifolds*, by Pere Menal-Ferrer, Joan Porti](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4338) and,
2. [*Twisted cohomology for hyperbolic three manifolds*, by Pere Menal-Ferrer Joan Porti](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.2242v2.pdf)

As to the third question, I am not sure what "remarkable" means here, so I will just leave that one alone.

Another interesting part of the story of character varieties of 3-manifold groups concerns dynamics.  See the very nice exposition by Dick Canary titled  [*Dynamics on character varieties: a survey*](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ecanary/DCVfinal.pdf) (and references therein).

Comment: Hi Sean, the arXiv 'front' site is down indefinitely, would you please update the links that point to papers/authors there? Having a 'this' or 'here' as a link work is also not good for future-proofing, giving the titles of the papers at a minimum would be better.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I have updated the links as you requested, and added the titles (editing the answer accordingly).  Thanks for your interest in my answer!

Comment: Thanks heaps! there are lots of these links, some more obscure than others. I'm slowly chipping away at the ones that can't be mass-edited with some kind of script.